# java intellij GUI form

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I know we can use gui form in the software, and the correspond code will be generated automatically. However now I copied some code and I want to see which part of the `GUI` the code correspond to. Is there any ways that after I enter the code the `GUI` form can be automatically generated.

Answer (score 0):

you will have named the elements and containers of your GUI. If not the program should have named them for you, I think.
You can just use the search function (Ctrl + F) to find any mention of that name in the code.